# How to configure heroku.yml having the docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, heroku, docker-compose

This is a very simple test app of two containers and can be deployed locally with `docker-compose.yml` and heroku doesn't support the `docker-compose.yml` file, in my opinion it does support it but partially that's why uses a file called `heroku.yml` instead.
I dont know how to configure `ports` in `heroku.yml`, and in the **docker** section; those names (*web_server* and *web_client*) are they dynos?, can I give them any name or just `web` and `worker`? and which would be which?
Any comment or suggestion please.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3"
services:
  api_server:
    image: api_server
    build: ./
    ports: 
      - 5000:5000
    networks: 
      - upload_app
  react_app:
    image: react_app
    build: ./client/
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks: 
      - upload_app
networks:
  upload_app:
    driver: bridge
```

*heroku.yml*

```
build:
  docker:
    web_server: Dockerfile
    web_client: ./client/Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct map between `docker-compose` (where you can deploy multiple applications) and `heroku.yml` (where you can define only one Web Dyno - hence one web application).

With `heroku.yml` you can deploy one application that includes one Web dyno and multiple workers, that's why you cannot define the ports. In Heroku you never define ports but it is typically the platform that provides you with the port you need via the `$PORT` env variable.

Here is my [blog](https://medium.com/geekculture/multiple-docker-images-on-heroku-3270ed31f2e5) post explaining `heroku.yml` limitations and an alternative.

Comment: Thank's but someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259434/deploy-to-heroku-multiple-docker-images-with-heroku-yml-recieve-the-error-no-d) looks like managed to deploy more than one container with `heroku.yml`, didn't read the blog yet.